# Add update and delete in same view with MVC3 and RAZOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I am new to MVC

I am using Entity Framework.

I have three database table Those are

```
User: UserID,UserName

Role: RoleID,RoleName

UserRoles: ID,UserID,RoleID
```

**UserDataModel.cs**

```
 [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public partial class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your again")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public String ConfirmPassword { get; set; }


}

public class UserMetaData
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You forgot to enter your name.")]
    [Display(Name = "Your Name")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Your name is too long. Please change your name if you can !")]
    public String UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Do you know your gender ?? if you don't know, leave it !!")]
    public Boolean Gender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You forgot to select your current country.")]
    public Int32 CountryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please tell us your 'Happy birth date'. We may brings you a huge gift for you on your birthday.")]
    [RegularExpression("^(((0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01])\\/(0[13578]|1[02])\\/((19|[2-9]\\d)\\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\\d|30)\\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\\/((19|[2-9]\\d)\\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])\\/02\\/((19|[2-9]\\d)\\d{2}))|(29\\/02\\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$", ErrorMessage = "Oh Noo!! Please enter date in dd/MM/yyy formate")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please tell us your email address. we assure you that we can't reach you with your email address.")]
    [RegularExpression("\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Oh Noo!! Please enter date in dd/MM/yyy formate")]
    public String Email { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please tell us your contact number. we assure that we wont give this number to anyone.")]
    public String ContactNo { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to select atleaset one role for you.")]
    //public List<Roles> Roles { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your security can not be compromised. Please enter your password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String Password { get; set; }




}
```

**RegistrationController.cs**

```
 DbMVCEntities db = new DbMVCEntities();

  public ActionResult RegisterUser()
  {
        return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterUser(User _user, string[] Roles)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Users.AddObject(_user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            for (int i = 0; i <= Roles.Length; i++)
            {
                UserRole _UserRole = new UserRole();
                _UserRole.UserID = _user.UserID;
                _UserRole.RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(Roles[0]);

                db.UserRoles.AddObject(_UserRole);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return RedirectToAction("RegisterUser");
    }


    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var User = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == id);
            if (User != null)
                return View("RegisterUser", User);
            else
                return RedirectToAction("RegisterUser");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**RegisterUser.cshtml**

```
@model MVCRegistration.User
@{
ViewBag.Title = "RegisterUser";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="15%">
            Name :
        </td>
        <td width="10%">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName)
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Your Name :
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, true)Male
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, false)Female
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Gender)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Country :
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryID, new SelectList((new MVCRegistration.DbMVCEntities()).Countries.ToList(), "CountryID", "CountryName"), "--Select--")
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CountryID)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Birth Date :
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DOB)
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DOB)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email :
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Contact No. :
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContactNo)
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ContactNo)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%" valign="top">
            Roles :
        </td>
        <td style="text-transform: lowercase;">
            @foreach (MVCRegistration.Role role in new MVCRegistration.DbMVCEntities().Roles)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="Roles" value="@role.RoleID" /> @role.RoleName <br />
            }
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Password :
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password)
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            System Password :
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
        </td>
        <td width="80%">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="submit" value="Register Me" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Gender
        </th>
        <th>
            Birth Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Country
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Contact No
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (MVCRegistration.User _user in new MVCRegistration.DbMVCEntities().Users)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @_user.UserName
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (@_user.Gender)
                {
                    @Html.Raw("Male");
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.Raw("Female");
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @_user.DOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            </td>
            <td>
                @_user.Country.CountryName
            </td>
            <td>
                @_user.Email
            </td>
            <td>
                @_user.ContactNo
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = _user.UserID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = _user.UserID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = _user.UserID })
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

}

Its working fine !!! when i click on edit all the data filled up except user roles checkbox.

Actually i am having roles list in "UserRoles".

How to get list of user roles in edit mode???????

Please help me out. If i am doing wrong anything please let me know.

Comment: What model are you using for RegisterUser.cshtml(). Normally you would use @Html.CheckBoxFor( model => model.SomeProperty ).

Comment: Please take a look of updated question...

Comment: Actually i am binding my check box list from "MasterRole" using foreach loop, and my view is of strongly type of "User".

Comment: Its just demo form to study ASP.NET MVC. If i am doing anything wrong  please just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why use

```
 @foreach (MVCRegistration.Role role in new MVCRegistration.DbMVCEntities().Roles)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="Roles" value="@role.RoleID" /> @role.RoleName <br />
            }
```

You can use

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < MVCRegistration.DbMVCEntities().Roles; i++)
{

@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.DbMVCEntities().Roles[i], new { @checked = "checked" })
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.DbMVCEntities().Roles[i])
}
```

Change user class to

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public partial class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your again")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public String ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Role> AllRoles { get; set; }
        public UserRoleModel()
{
    this.AllRoles = DbMVCEntities().Roles.Select(r => new Role
    {
        Name = r
    });

}   
}
```

Then u can use this `AllRoles` in view

Comment: ya its true, but when i am in create mode i need to display all the roles in "MasterRole"

Comment: Didnt get ur requirement

Comment: At the first an empty form and grid with all user is there. but when i click on edit from grid view for particular row for will filled up with information that is stored in database. hope you got my problem.

Comment: cant u have one model field which will be filled with all users roles when called action. you can then use that list to bind to checkboxes. Hope it helps. Please post ur code for Edit action

Comment: In my question RegistrationController.cs, i have edit action.

Answer (score 0):

Does the submit of your form work - is `public ActionResult RegisterUser(User _user, string[] Roles)` get called with the data you expect?

Normally your model would be what you submit. So, I would make the MVCRegistration.DbMVCEntities().Roles list a member of the model. Such as `Roles`. You can specify the [NotMapped] attribute so that EF does not think that it is mapped to the DB. Then you would do something like:

```
        @for(int i = 0; i< Model.Roles.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor( x => x.Roles[i] );
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean that in my UserDataModel.cs i should have a one more property which is List<UserRoles> Roles ???

Comment: Yes, unless I am missing something about your design.